# How do you type a semi colon on visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to type a semi colon, the character ";" in visual studio code.

Every time I type a semicolon, it imports the proposed class. For example if I want to type `temp;` what ends up being written is `SVGMetadataElement`.

Comment: Disable the extension and see if it still happens?

Comment: And to be clear, you are talking about Visual Studio Code, not Visual Studio, right?

Comment: Yeah the free one, @Blorgbeard it still does it when disabled.

Comment: Well I guess it wasn't that extension then. What if you disable all of them? What kind of file are you editing when this happens?

Comment: @Blorgbeard typescript files, I think it's an inherent feature of Visual studio actually. You don't have it when the intellisens pops up and you press ;? I tried to disable all of them and it still does it.

Comment: Nope. The intellisense pops up, but only pressing enter or tab causes it to actually do the replacement. I can type `temp;` just fine.

Comment: Anything in your user preferences?

Comment: @Blorgbeard nothing that would cause this. But I got a belgian keyboard, My semi colon key is right above the ALT GR one. I checked an image of the querty keyboard and it seems like it's the " , " key at the same place. Could you try with the " , " key ? the key above space and alt gr

Comment: Nope, `temp,` works fine too for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you have a Belgian keyboard - my guess it that it's registering as a period, which should have the behavior you describe.

File an issue on Github, it might be a bug.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode